# React JS: Remove a Localstorage value when the page reloads. onbeforeunload should not be used acc to my senior dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my first question in this forum. Please let me know if I made any mistake on asking this question.
I am implementing a popup modal that has to be shown only once for newly signed up user.
I'm setting a local variable ("popup") when the signup is successful. I'm calling this modal inside my parent component if the local Storage variable exists. I tried using the useEffect with return, but it is not working on reload. Basically it renders my component multiple times, so the value gets erased and the popup just flashes and disappears. I want to have the value erased only when all the rendering is done.

Edit: I am setting the localStorage variable on response of the API, I can confirm that it's set. I don't know how to post that code here. But basically in the parent component, where I receive data from API, I'm setting the variable.

My parent component code where I call the modal:

```
{
  localStorage.getItem("popup") && <PopUpModal />;
}
```

My modal component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("popup");
  };
});

return <div>//content</div>;
```

Comment: You might want to look into dependency parameter of `useEffect`. Try using something like `useEffect(() => ..., []);

Comment: Can you add in your code where you are setting the `localStorage`
 ?

Comment: @yousoumar I have edited the post. Thanks

Comment: @Grimson I want to remove localStorage only after all rendering is completed. I tried using that It did not work since it removed it in the initial render itself

Comment: Basically my page renders 6 times before it stops re rendering. Found it by console.count on render part of the popup

Comment: By the information, you have provided. The popup removes the localStorage during the first unmount. And then it continues to remove it in the subsequent rerenders too but the catch is the item has already been removed. One way to overcome this would be to memoize with `React.memo()` the popup component so, it only renders once so, it will be the final rendering where the localStorage is cleared.